# Pull headerText from JSON into results div, based on selection from dropdown

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to pull the headerText from JSON based on the option the user selects, and have it populate the results div of my code. I can pull the hex color and change the box background, but can't get the headerText out. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
```

JSON

```
var json = {
    "dropdown": [
    {
        "optionText": "Budget Starter",
        "headerText": "Work 1-on-1 with your expert to build new spending habits (and break some old ones). Get on a real, sustainable budget that fits your lifestyle.",
        "color": "#59c5c7"
    },
    {
        "optionText": "5 Year Planner",
        "headerText": "Declare what you want - freedom from debt, security for your family, or an amazing trip. Your expert will build you a custom plan to help you get there.",
        "color": "#009cd0"
    },
    {
        "optionText": "Portfolio Builder",
        "headerText": "Start training for the world's hardest game: investing. Your expert will help you grow into a disciplined and balanced portfolio manager.",
        "color": "#39ad74"
    }
]
};
```

jQuery:

```
$('#fetch').click(function() {
    $.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify(json)}, function(data) {
        var dropdown = $('#dropdown');
        $.each(data.dropdown, function(i, v) {
            var option = $('<option value="' + v.color + '">' + v.optionText + '</option>');
            option.data('header', v.headerText).appendTo(dropdown);
        });
    });
});
//change color of header container based on dropdown selection
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    $("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val()).text($(this).data('header'));
}).change();
```

CSS:

```
#result {
    height: 50px;
}
#dropdown, #fetch {
    position: relative; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `/echo/json/` doesn't seem to be a valid file name

Comment: I have my JSON on the same page as the jQuery. I'm able to pull the optionText and hex color, I just can't get the headerText into the results div.

Comment: so where is the `.json` file?

Comment: hum.. so could you explain to me what `/echo/json/` means ?

Comment: its not an external file. It's within the same page as the rest of the code.

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(v.headerText)` - looks legit to me, with the exception of maybe what you are doing with it....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RZv9a/

Comment: well... it works with `/echo/json/` and nothing else... could anyone explain me why oO? Is this a standard way of echoing json string ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace the dropdown change code with this logic.it will work for you

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    $("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    $("#result").html($(this).find("option:selected").data("header"));
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Problem was in

```
$("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val()).text(
   $(this).data('header')  // <--
);
```

$(this) is a select in this case, not the selected option.

```
//change color of header container based on dropdown selection
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var headerText = $('option:selected', this).data('header');
    $("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val()).text(headerText);
}).change();
```